# Python Socket with Threading can not work correctly

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, sockets

I am really new to socket programming with threading in python. As the input() function has a blocking effect,the client first finished a message, can only wait for the other end of the message sent to continue to send messages.so i think i can make sending and receiving separately, so i consider the multi-threaded,and here are my code:

server.py

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from socket import *

import threading

HOST = ""
PORT = 21567
BUFSIZE = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

tcpSerSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcpSerSock.bind(ADDR)
tcpSerSock.listen(4)

print("waiting for connection...")
tcpCliSock, addr = tcpSerSock.accept()
print("...connected from:", addr)

def rec(tcpCliSock):
    while True:
        data = tcpCliSock.recv(1024).decode()
        if data == "exit":
            break
        print('From Client:', data)

chat = threading.Thread(target=rec, args=(tcpCliSock, ))
chat.start()

while True:
    data = input(">")
    if data == "exit":
        break
    tcpCliSock.send(data.encode())
tcpSerSock.close()
```

client.py

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from socket import *

import threading

HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 21567
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST,PORT)

tcpCliSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcpCliSock.connect(ADDR)

def rec(tcpCliSock):
    while True:
        data = tcpCliSock.recv(1024).decode()
        if data == "exit":
        print('From Server:', data)

chat = threading.Thread(target=rec, args=(tcpCliSock, ))
chat.start()

while True:
    data = input(">")
    if data == "exit":
        break
    tcpCliSock.send(data.encode())

tcpCliSock.close()
```

Ok,these are my code,when i try to run them directly in the IDLE of python3.6.1,it will not work properly,that is to say,when you send message from client to server,you must pess "Enter" in the server to show the message from the client,it can not show immediatelly.it is the same when the message from the server to client.Can not show automatically is terrible for me,i am really confused about this.

So please tell me what should i do if i want them work correctly in IDLE.

Thanks for you help!

By the way,they can run right in CMD of windows in my laptop(64).

Comment: First thing in the rec method of the client you forgot to break the loop when data is exit

Comment: I'm sorry to give you a reply so late, you are right, i really forgot to break the loop when data is exit, but i think it is not important thing to solve at now. what confuse me is that how to make data to achieve real-time display, rather than the  user have got to press "Enter" to make data immediately show.

Comment: sorry but your code works well for me, I guess it is because I use python 2.x, what I suggestt is to put the 2nd while loop in another thread, I hope this helps